# EFI partition is 99 MB (instead of 100 MB)

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint, uefi

I'm trying to install Linux Mint on an Intel NUC 4th gen. I first installed Windows 8.1 Professional 64 bit, I ended up with 3 partitions created automatically:

- 300 MB (recovery partition)
- 99 MB (efi system partition)
- 80 GB C:

Apparently the size of the EFI partition required by Linux Mint is at minimum 100 MB, which aborts the installation.

Is this issue new to Windows 8? Can anyone suggest a way around this or should I reinstall everything from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've just started, it might be simplest to start afresh, but this time, manually create an ESP that's big enough.

If it were important to keep what you've got, you could use GParted or a similar Windows tool to resize the ESP and the Windows `C:` partition, but that would mean moving the start of the Windows `C:` partition, which is a time-consuming and relatively dangerous operation.

---

P.S.: You might consider filing a bug report on this issue. ESPs *can* be much smaller than 100MiB and still work, although most people advise creating them bigger than this value.